# Which sentence is correct, in or no in?

Tags: grammar

> (1) That is, it is not the lack of technical solutions (pumps, reservoirs, dams, etc.) that is the main obstacle explaining why they lack access to safe water.
>
> (2) That is, it is not the lack of technical solutions (pumps, reservoirs, dams, etc.) that is the main obstacle **in** explaining why they lack access to safe water.

Which sentence of the two is correct?  I think sentence (1), the one with no *in*, is correct since I see the phrase "the main obstacle" as the subject for explaining.   Could you help me clarify it?

Comment: I'd say the "best" form is neither of your alternatives. *It is not the lack of technical solutions (pumps, reservoirs, dams, etc.) that is the main obstacle **to** explaining why they lack access to safe water*.

Answer (score 0):

You will see both though neither is excellent English. The obstacle, whatever it may be, is unlikely to be explaining itself. Moreover, the sentence "The iron bars are an obstacle in escaping" is at least awkward and perhaps not idiomatic in American English. Far more common would be "The iron bars are an obstacle to escaping."

I'd suggest "obstacle to explaining" instead of # 1 or # 2.

Any such construction is unnecessarily wordy. "In other words, lack of technical means such as pumps does not explain the lack of safe water" is better style in my opinion. (Of course, style is subjective.)

EDIT: As a result of Katy's comment, I now believe that the quoted sentence does not express clearly enough the intended meaning. "Explaining" and "obstacles" are metaphors that obscure a very simple thought. Fussing with improving the wording of those metaphors leaves that thought still obscured.

> The lack of safe water is not primarily caused by a lack of technical means such as pumps.

The intent presumably is to discuss the **primary causes** of unsafe water. So say so directly

Comment: I have to disagree. "Obstacle to escaping" and "obstacle to explaining" are not equivalent constructions here. Including "to" makes it sound like a lack of technical solutions is the obstacle that prevents explanations, the same way the bars would be the obstacle preventing escape. I would absolutely choose the first sentence over either "in" or "to," though I do think the best solution would be to rephrase the whole sentence: "The lack of technical solutions is not the main obstacle preventing access to safe water."

Comment: @Katy You have a very good point. Unforunately, "obstacle to" is what is idiomatic. "Obstacle explaining" makes no sense: obstacles do not explain. But "obstacle to" comes into play only if you insist on that word in what is a verbose sentence. Rewriting is what is needed. I shall edit. Thank you.